# Is there a way to select values from a dataframe by indexing with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, vlookup

I have 2 dataframes, both identical lengths but with different sizes.

Essentially, I want to select the values in ref_df by using the values in df1['Data1'] as the columns input.

Below, you can see my solution, but is there a way to do this without using .ix or without using for loop? Also, how would I do this if my index was a datetime index instead of ['11','12','13','14']?

```
    import pandas as pd 
    import numpy as np 


    data = {'21' : [1,2,3,4], '22' : [5,6,7,8], '23' : [9,10,11,12], '24' : [13,14,15,16]} 
    ref_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['11','12','13','14']) 
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['11','12','13','14'],'Data1': ['21','22','23','24']}) 

    for index, row in df1.iterrows(): 
        df1.ix[index, 'Derived'] = ref_df.iloc[ref_df.index.get_loc(row.Data), ref_df.columns.get_loc(row.Data1)]



df1   Data Data1
0   11    21
1   12    22
2   13    23
3   14    24
-----------
ref df     21  22  23  24
11   1   5   9  13
12   2   6  10  14
13   3   7  11  15
14   4   8  12  16
---------
df1   Data Data1  Derived
0   11    21      1.0
1   12    22      6.0
2   13    23     11.0
3   14    24     16.0
----------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `columns` of `df1` are in order as per `ref_df` `index` and `columns`, you can take diagonal values of `ref_df` as:

```
df1['Derived'] = np.diag(ref_df)

print(df1)
  Data Data1  Derived
0   11    21        1
1   12    22        6
2   13    23       11
3   14    24       16
```

If not aligned change the order in `ref_df` according to `df1` and use.

Or Use [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html#pandas.DataFrame.lookup) directly:

```
df1['Derived'] = ref_df.lookup(df1['Data'], df1['Data1'])
```

Comment: The values in ref_df are random, and cant be aligned to be diagonal. It wasn't meant to be intentional in this case.

Comment: @hyrian Check the update.

Comment: Thanks!! This does exactly what I want it to do, even works with a datetime index!